# Adding multiple rows to a table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have gone through a solution suggested for this subject but I declined to use it because it is cumbersome for large number of columns. Below is a small version of my table. I have included two buttons. One alllows me to add one row at a time to the table. This works fine. However i want the user to add as many rows as desired with a single click. This is not working. Can javascript not do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bio-probotics</title>
   <style type="text/css">
    body {font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica,Sans-serif; padding: 1px;  
    font  size: 14px;}
    th {font-weight: bold; text-align: left; border: 1px; border-style: 
    solid; margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse;}
    td {font-weight: normal; text-align: left; border: 1px; border-style: 
    solid; margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse;}
    .total {font-weight: bold}
    .chem:focus {background-color: rgb(250,250,150);}
    .hidecell {border: 0px; margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse;}
    .nofoc {font-weight: bold; text-align: right;}
    .newRow {font-weight: bold; border: 0px; width: 200px; font-style: 
    italic; background-color: rgb(240,240,240);}
    .newRow:hover {background-color: rgb(255,255,150);}
    </style>
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="pr">
    <thead>
    <tr id="thd">
    <th>s/n</th>
    <th>Enzyme Name</th>
    <th>Cat 1</th>
    <th>Cat 2</th>
    <th>Cat 3</th>
    <th>Energy Level</th>
    <th>BioImpluse</th>
    <th>Simulant</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="mpf">
    <td id="sn" input type="text" class="chem" name="sn" /></td>
    <td id="ename"><input type="text" class="chem" name="ename" /></td>
     <td id="cat1">
    <select>
      <option>P100</option>
      <option>P200</option>
      <option>P300</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <select id="cat2">
      <option>C384A</option>
      <option>C384B</option>
      <option>C384C</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <select id="cat3">
      <option>EMQ65</option>
      <option>EMQ84</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td id="el"><input type="text" class="chem" onchange="update((this));"  
    /></td>
    <td id="bi"><input type="text" class="chem" onchange="update((this));" 
    /></td>
    <td id="bi"><input type="text" class="chem" onchange="update((this));" 
    /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot id="tft">
    <tr>
    <td class="hidecell" /></td>
    <td class="hidecell" /></td>
    <td class="hidecell" /></td>
    <td class="hidecell" /></td>
    <td class="total"><b>Total</b></td>
    <td id="col6" class="nofoc"><input type="text" readonly /></td>
    <td id="col7" class="nofoc"><input type="text" readonly /></td>
    <td id="col8" class="nofoc"><input type="text" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
    <input id="newRow" class="newRow" onclick="addRow()" value="Click to Add 
    one Row @ in one click" readonly>
    <br><br>
    <input id="newRows" class="newRow" onclick="addRows()" value="Click to 
    Add 40 Rows @ one click" readonly>
    <br>

    <script>
    function addRow(){
        var tbl, elmnt, cln;
        tbl = document.getElementById('pr');
        elmnt = tbl.getElementsByTagName("TR")[1];
        cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
        tbl.tBodies[0].appendChild(cln);
        }
    </script>

    <script>
    function addRows(){
    var i; tbl, elmnt, cln;
        for (i = 1, i = 40, i++) {
        tbl = document.getElementById('pr');
        elmnt = tbl.getElementsByTagName("TR")[1];
        cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
        tbl.tBodies[0].appendChild(cln);
        }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you please just post your entire webpage? Oh wait you did

Comment: Please check my answer... which is working

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can. In your `addRows()` function you can make use of `addRow()` function so you don't need to repeat the logic. Replace your `addRows()` function with this:

```
function addRows() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 40; i++)
            addRow();
}
```

This will create 39 table rows.
Also your HTML code has some syntax errors in it, so I'd recommend to use some kind of HTML validator tool to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

I have just update your code . there are several mistake that i have updated.
You can jst replace **addRow()** and **addRows()** functions

Please check this code

```js
function addRows(){
    var i, tbl, elmnt, cln;
        for (i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        tbl = document.getElementById('pr');
        elmnt = tbl.getElementsByTagName("TR")[1];
        cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
        tbl.tBodies[0].appendChild(cln);
        }
    }

function addRow(){
        var tbl, elmnt, cln;
        tbl = document.getElementById('pr');
        elmnt = tbl.getElementsByTagName("TR")[1];
        cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
        tbl.tBodies[0].appendChild(cln);
        }
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica,Sans-serif; padding: 1px;  
    font  size: 14px;}
    th {font-weight: bold; text-align: left; border: 1px; border-style: 
    solid; margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse;}
    td {font-weight: normal; text-align: left; border: 1px; border-style: 
    solid; margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse;}
    .total {font-weight: bold}
    .chem:focus {background-color: rgb(250,250,150);}
    .hidecell {border: 0px; margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse;}
    .nofoc {font-weight: bold; text-align: right;}
    .newRow {font-weight: bold; border: 0px; width: 200px; font-style: 
    italic; background-color: rgb(240,240,240);}
    .newRow:hover {background-color: rgb(255,255,150);}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bio-probotics</title>
   <style type="text/css">
   
    </style>
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="pr">
    <thead>
    <tr id="thd">
    <th>s/n</th>
    <th>Enzyme Name</th>
    <th>Cat 1</th>
    <th>Cat 2</th>
    <th>Cat 3</th>
    <th>Energy Level</th>
    <th>BioImpluse</th>
    <th>Simulant</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="mpf">
    <td id="sn" input type="text" class="chem" name="sn" /></td>
    <td id="ename"><input type="text" class="chem" name="ename" /></td>
     <td id="cat1">
    <select>
      <option>P100</option>
      <option>P200</option>
      <option>P300</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <select id="cat2">
      <option>C384A</option>
      <option>C384B</option>
      <option>C384C</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <select id="cat3">
      <option>EMQ65</option>
      <option>EMQ84</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td id="el"><input type="text" class="chem" onchange="update((this));"  
    /></td>
    <td id="bi"><input type="text" class="chem" onchange="update((this));" 
    /></td>
    <td id="bi"><input type="text" class="chem" onchange="update((this));" 
    /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot id="tft">
    <tr>
    <td class="hidecell" /></td>
    <td class="hidecell" /></td>
    <td class="hidecell" /></td>
    <td class="hidecell" /></td>
    <td class="total"><b>Total</b></td>
    <td id="col6" class="nofoc"><input type="text" readonly /></td>
    <td id="col7" class="nofoc"><input type="text" readonly /></td>
    <td id="col8" class="nofoc"><input type="text" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
    <input id="newRow" class="newRow" onclick="addRow()" value="Click to Add 
    one Row @ in one click" readonly>
    <br><br>
    <input id="newRows" class="newRow" onclick="addRows()" value="Click to 
    Add 40 Rows @ one click" readonly>
    <br>

   
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, simply add input where user will type how many rows he want to add, read value and use **for** which will execute addRow() function.

```
<input type="text" id="num_rows">
```

And edit Javascript to this:

```
function addRows() {
  var rows = document.getElementById('num_rows');
  if(rows < 150) {  //check for some limit
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
     addRow();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Many txs for your input. Works just fine. I appreciate